# How to invoke method on click on only visible part of animage view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` in my application and **I have attached a gesture recognizer to that image view.**

My problem is that **I need to invoke its action only if a touch on its visible area occurs, and not when it occurs on its transparent parts.**

How can I acheive this?

Comment: If you just need the touch and call to touch handler use view hierarchy ie use UIView as container and put UIImageview as its subview and make the frame if UIImageview the size of image and apply gesture recognizer to the UIImageview only :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at github  for the OBSHAPED button .it will resolve your problem Happy coding.:)

Answer (score 1):

These code snippets should get you started. **This first piece is a category on `UIView`** (that I got somewhere on SO, but I don't remember where). `This gets you the color under the touch point.`

```
@interface UIView (ColorOfPoint)

- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point;

@end


- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color;
}
```

This second piece shows how I call this method in a custom image view class:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self];
    self.pickedColor = [self colorOfPoint:loc];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ColorPicked" object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

**I used a notification here, because I needed to let another class know the value of the picked color.**

Answer (score 0):

U CAN USE THIS FOR GETTING ALPHA OF THE TOUCHED POINT

```
-(UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point
{

    CGImageRef inImage;
    UIColor *color = nil;


        inImage = [self.imageView.image CGImage];


    CGContextRef context = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
    if(context == NULL) return nil;
    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 
    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, inImage); 
    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (context);
    if (data != NULL)
    {

        //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int offset;



            offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x)); 


        int alpha =  data[offset];
        int red = data[offset+1];
        int green = data[offset+2];
        int blue = data[offset+3];
        //NSLog(@"%@",name);
        NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i ",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];

    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(context);
    // Free image data memory for the context
    if (data)
    { 
        free(data);
    }
    return color;
}
-(CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) inImage 
{

    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();//CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```